# Match file names using Linux Shell regex

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I need a way to match file names in directory.

For example I have three files:

```
CAt_DoG_ZebRa.TXT
MOUSE_lion_deer_BIRD.TXT
fIsh_biRD_LION.TXT
```

I am not regex expert by any means, however I've used something like this in SnapLogic and Pentaho before:

```
(?i).*(?=.*bird)(?=.*lion).*.TXT
```

The above would match all file names that contain the words 'bird' and 'lion' with case being ignored and the order of the words would not matter. Very powerful! So it would match these two:

```
MOUSE_lion_deer_BIRD.TXT    
fIsh_biRD_LION.TXT
```

I tried lots of variations of the above in conjunction with find and grep to no avail. For example:

```
find . -regex ".*/(?i).*(?=.*bird)(?=.*lion).*.TXT"
```

The above find does not match anything.

Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Comment: So you want to match files that contain either lion or bird? ie `Cat_dog_zebra` would not be included?

Comment: That contain both lion and bird. Yes Cat_dog_zebra would not be included.

Comment: Find's `-regex` isn't PCRE (the syntax you're writing your code for here) by default in any implementation of `find` I know of. On a GNU system, if you see the man page, you'll see a `-regextype` letting you select the syntax you want.

Comment: That said, I don't know why you'd need regex for this at all. If regular globs couldn't do it, extglobs could -- and bash 4 or zsh, you have a sufficiently powerful globbing syntax to not need `find` at all even in the recursive case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ls
asdafsdfdBirdasfdfd.txt      dasdbirdbfdgdlionb.txt       fgdfLionqweBirdaqw.txt   
# ls | /usr/gnu/bin/grep -i -E '.*(bird.*lion|lion.*bird).*\.txt'
dasdbirdbfdgdlionb.txt
fgdfLionqweBirdaqw.txt
```

a trick: when you writing some regular expression using look ahead or look behind, doubt it, and either change another way to write it or think about whether regular expression is a suitable tool for this problem.

Comment: The only thing slightly unfortunate here is that it may not be clear to readers that the use of `ls` is for example only, as opposed to an example of good practice. (See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for discussion of how using `ls` in scripting leads to bugs).

Comment: The lookaround is necessary because it's forcing it to match BOTH words, which yours doesn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true. that's bad.

Answer (score 7):

```
shopt -s globstar   # enable recursive globs
shopt -s nocaseglob # make globs case-insensitive
for file in ./**/*bird*lion*.txt; do
  echo "found: $file"
done
```

...or, if you didn't care about order between those words:

```
shopt -s globstar   # enable recursive globs
shopt -s nocaseglob # make globs case-insensitive
shopt -s extglob    # enable extended globbing syntax
for file in ./**/*@(bird*lion|lion*bird)*.txt; do
  echo "found: $file"
done
```

Comment: He wants to match a file only if it has BOTH words in it. This doesn't do what he wants.

Comment: @BrianStephens, edited; now it does (with the potential bug of including duplicate results if files contain one of the two words more than once).

Comment: @BrianStephens, ...and, now, lacking even that bug.

Comment: That should catch it all cleanly. Nice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I threw your code in a script and tried to execute but i'm getting some errors: ./match_script.sh: line 1: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name found: ./**/*@(birdlion|lionbird)*.txt ./match_script.sh: line 7: /home/mdmdusr: is a directory –

Comment: @Soyf, that means you're not using a sufficiently new bash; this code requires 4.0 or newer.

Comment: @Soyf, ...also, be sure that your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

First, [find](/questions/tagged/find) doesn't support PCRE regex engine, so this a solution for your problem, with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (recursive) :

```
 bash -c "shopt -s globstar; perl -lne 'print if /i.*bird/i and /i.*lion/i' **"
```

This solution work with all filenames matching bird and lion, in any orders

Comment: He wants to match a file only if it has BOTH words in it. You need to change the OR to AND in the first solution. In your 2nd solution, change the regex back to what he had and it should work.